# How to verify correctness of a dynamic programming solution to a competitive programming task?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am trying to develop **systematic method to came up with dynamic programming (DP) solutions** - following certain steps you can came up with a valid solution to a problem.

**Idea, essentially, is the following:** you start from recursion, tune it to minimize number of parameters, which allows you to define problem and add memoization, after that you can easily came up with a DP solution. It turns out that it is not that simple.

One can't simply transfer recursive solution into DP.
E.g. see the subset sum PS from USACO http://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=9OS8tkGfsX5&S=subset

Here is the code where my approach of turning recursion into DP is used.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_SUBSETSUM = (39+1)*39/4;
const int MAX_N = 39;
int memo[MAX_SUBSETSUM+1][MAX_N+1];
const int NOT_VISITED = -1;
// resembles 0-1 knapsack problem
// we need to select numbers that will go to
// the first set and those sum is totalSum/2
// so we have two sets of equal sum
int recur(int sum, int num) {
  int counter = 0;
  // ### 1.Base case
  if(sum == 0)
    return 1;
  if(sum < 0 || num <= 0)
    return 0;

  // ### Memoization
  if(memo[sum][num] != NOT_VISITED)
    return memo[sum][num];

  // ### 2.Recursive step
  for(int nextNum = 1; nextNum < num; ++nextNum) {
    if(nextNum > sum)
      break;
    //### 3. Make a decision
    const int withNumber = recur(sum - num, nextNum);
    const int withOutNumber = recur(sum, nextNum);
    counter = withNumber + withOutNumber;
  }
  memo[sum][num] = counter;
  return counter;
}


int solveDP(int subsetSum, int N) {
  if(subsetSum & 1)
    return 0;

  int dp[MAX_SUBSETSUM+1][MAX_N+1];
  memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
  // fill in base cases
  for(int i = 0; i <= N; ++i) {
    // when subsetsum is 0, we have one way (we pick no nubers)
    dp[0][i] = 1;
  }

  for(int sum =1; sum <=subsetSum; ++sum) {
    for(int num = 1; num <= N; ++num) {
      if(sum >= num)
        dp[sum][num] = dp[sum - num][num-1]/*with num*/ + dp[sum][num-1]/*without*/;
      else 
        dp[sum][num] = dp[sum][num-1]/*without*/;
    }
  }
  return dp[subsetSum][N]/2; // NB!!! /2 - came up with it
}

int main() {
  //freopen("preface.in", "r", stdin);
  //freopen("preface.out", "w", stdout);
  const int N = 7;
  const int subsetSum = (N+1)*N/4;
  memset(memo, NOT_VISITED, sizeof(memo));
  int res = recur(subsetSum, N);
  res = solveDP(subsetSum, N);
  return 0;
}
```

In DP you have to half result(see `return dp[subsetSum][N]/2;`). And I found it because I got 2 versions and results differed, so it involved something like trial and error method to adjust DP to recursion.
I was able to understand why is what only after I played with DP table with paper and a pen, so I noticed that results are double counted.
That helped me.

But what to do when you got DP problem in a programming contest, you are limited in time and can't, obviously, afford to play around with DP table,
can you advise some techniques that will allow to validate results of my DP solution to make sure that it is correct.

My aim is to reduce amount of time and number of incorrect attempts.

Comment: The simplest way to validate would be to cross-check results: produce a result using both methods, and ensure that they are equal. If the test fails, you have a problem.

Comment: @Ober, this is what I did. Possible bottleneck here - you can have 2 buggy versions that converges to the same result ) Also, in my opinion, it is evident that to write 2 versions you need to spend more time when on one version, given that this all happens during competition, where you submissions are timed I don't thing this is the most efficient method to use, although it works

Answer (score -2):

make a simple brute force program and run a small test input to compare the
result from brute force and your DP program. **"When in doubt, use brute force"**